# Replacement for deprecated CRM_Core_OptionGroup::getValue

Tags: developer

I noticed that CRM_Core_OptionGroup::getValue is deprecated - though still used fairly extensively in the codebase. It is noted that values are not cached.

Presumably the preferred function is CRM_Core_PseudoConstant::getKey, but this function actually seems to be slower? What are the advantages of this over the deprecated function?

Comment: Did you measure how slower it was? just curious

Comment: On a single run it's ~10x slower. However if you loop the call multiple times (more than ~30) then it starts outperforming, presumably due to the caching! It's 2x faster over 10,000 runs. So I suppose that answers my own question in part...